How do I stop a record update if an API callout fails?
So I have a record, it's got a bunch of info inside of it that needs to be synced with an external database via an API call.
I've built a pretty solid means of making that api call, which sends the data and edits to the external database and then sends back a response that confirms it works. This works fine.
However, I've now run into an issue where if the API call fails, the data in Salesforce needs to not update so the two databases are synced in terms of data.
The API Callout utilizes a @future method, so It's proving difficult to work with. We've tried raising errors, re-updating the data with a copy of the old object, a few ideas with flows, but everything just gets rejected.
Any ideas?

This is a very frequently asked question - have you done a search here? The short answer is "it depends". One option - in your @future after you call out, you can execute a DML statement performing a compensating (undo) transaction if the callout fails.

I... Am not aware of any kind of undo transaction. Is that a possibility? I'm really looking for any means of disrupting or undoing the transaction you can think of.
I apologize for the vague nature of my question's specifics.

An undo aka compensating transaction is along the lines of re-updating the data with a copy of the old object . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/compensating-transaction
